# Laravel DB Seeder won't seed in console

Tags: php, laravel

Hi I have the following seeder class I am trying to seed. When I run the php artisan db:seed command the only thing that seeds is my previous seeder class I created a few weeks ago. I have no idea what I am missing. I inserted SoftDeletes and Protected fillables as well.

Here is my seeder class:

```
    public function run()
{
    DB::table('leave_type')->insert([
      [
        'leaveType' => 'Vacation Leave'
      ],
      [
        'leaveType' => 'Sick Leave'
      ],
      [
        'leaveType' => 'Afternoon Off'
      ],
      [
        'leaveType' => 'Special Leave'
      ],
      [
        'leaveType' => 'Study Leave'
      ],
    ]);
}
```

My model:

```
    namespace App;

    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

    class LeaveType extends Model
     {
       protected $fillable = ['leaveType'];
       protected $table ="leave_type";
       use SoftDeletes;
       public $timestamps = true;
    }
```

Comment: run `composer dump-auto` first, then db:seed - laravel might not know about the new seeder class yet. Also make sure your seeder is registered.

Comment: Did you add your seeder to the `DatabaseSeeder.php` ?

Comment: That is what I forgot! Thanks - didnt add it to database seeder class.

Comment: model is ok .but you not use model

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Converting my comment to answer;

1. Make sure laravel knows about the new database seeder class you've generated by running this command:

> composer dump-auto

2. Make sure your seeder class is registered in `{PROJECT}/database/seeds/DatabaseSeeder.php` like this:

> $this->call(YourNewSeeder::class);

Then you could refresh the database (rollback all migration, re-run the migration) and run the seeder in one go with this command:

> php artisan migrate:refresh --seed

or just run the specific seeder only like this:

> php artisan db:seed --class=YourNewSeeder

Comment: Tiny typo in `php artisan migrate:refreh --seed`, should be `refresh`.